# Howler.js 3D sound positionning with static listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, howler.js

I have been messing around with Howler.js and its Spatial plugin, but can't seem to position sounds appropriately. My end goal is to have a static listener in the "middle" of the screen, facing straight ahead.

Then, I have 8 sounds that need to be positionned around said listener and play as if the sound came from their location towards the listener.

LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN, UP, UP_LEFT, DOWN_LEFT, UP_RIGHT, DOWN_RIGHT
LEFT and RIGHT are not a problem and work just fine. The rest however, does not...

```
// Listener position
Howler.pos(0,0,-0.5)

// Audio source positions
$("#play-left").click(function(){
    soundsList[dirCodes.LEFT].clip.pos(-1)
    soundsList[dirCodes.LEFT].clip.play()
})

$("#play-right").click(function(){
    soundsList[dirCodes.RIGHT].clip.pos(1)
    soundsList[dirCodes.RIGHT].clip.play()
})

$("#play-up").click(function(){
    soundsList[dirCodes.UP].clip.pos(0, -1)
    soundsList[dirCodes.UP].clip.play()
})

$("#play-down").click(function(){
    soundsList[dirCodes.DOWN].clip.pos(0,1)
    soundsList[dirCodes.DOWN].clip.play()
})

$("#play-top-left").click(function(){
    soundsList[dirCodes.UP_LEFT].clip.pos(-1, -1, 5)
    soundsList[dirCodes.UP_LEFT].clip.play()
})

$("#play-top-right").click(function(){
    soundsList[dirCodes.UP_RIGHT].clip.pos(1, -1, 5)
    soundsList[dirCodes.UP_RIGHT].clip.play()
})

$("#play-bottom-left").click(function(){
    soundsList[dirCodes.DOWN_LEFT].clip.pos(1, -1, -5)
    soundsList[dirCodes.DOWN_LEFT].clip.play()
})

$("#play-bottom-right").click(function(){
    soundsList[dirCodes.DOWN_RIGHT].clip.pos(1, 1, -5)
    soundsList[dirCodes.DOWN_RIGHT].clip.play()
})
```

I feel stupid, but it seems like I'm missing something. It appears as though these 3D coordinates are right... Any ideas?

Many thanks!